# 'A is not generally equal to B' or 'A is generally not equal to B'?

Tags: word-order

Which one is more appropriate? Personally, I often take the second version. But once my supervisor changed my writing to the first version.

Comment: With ***generally*** (or ***usually*** or ***often***, for example) it makes no difference whether you put the negating ***not*** before or after the adverb - they're both syntactically valid and mean the same, so it's just a stylistic choice. It would be different with , say, ***always***, because there's a difference in meaning. *A is not always equal to B* implies that *A=B is **sometimes** true*, but *A is always not equal to B* asserts that *A=B is **never** true*.

Comment: While **_generally_** means "usually" or "often" in general English, when speaking about formal proofs (and it sounds as though the asker is), it can mean "_**universally**_". Because of this ambiguity the supervisor is right to choose the first version.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Hi, I hope you don't mind I have a quick question after reading your comment above: can the phrase "*in most cases*" mean "*usually*"?

Comment: @MathDoctor: Yes, indeed - *in most cases = usually = more often than not* all "explicitly" quantify something as applying to *over 50% of all (relevant) situations*. Whereas plain ***often*** might refer to anywhere from 1% to 99% of the time (if it's 1% you might say that's "often" if arguing with someone who claims it only happens once in a *tens of millions* of cases, and can therefore be ignored).

Answer (score 2):

I know this was asked, and answered, eons ago. However, here is my take, for posterity.

A is generally equal to B == (in most cases A==B)

A is generally not equal to B == (in most cases A!=B)

A is not generally equal to B == (The assumption that "in most cases A==B" is not true)

Answer (score 1):

> A is not generally equal to B

Here, you are saying "equal" doesn't generally (i.e. usually) happen.

You can be implying that A could be something else to B, rather than equal.

> A is generally not equal to B

Here, you are saying "A equals B" doesn't generally (i.e. usually) happen, but there is no additional implication.